# How to exclude a dependency from remote mavenpom?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a local pom which uses mahout-0.8 dependency. Mahout pom includes hadoop-core dependency with 1.1.2 version. [Link to mahout-0.8 pom](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.8/pom.xml)

But in my project I need the latest hadoop-core, which is 2.2.0 version. As I have read hadoop-core-2.2.0 is built from these dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

So I need to exclude dependency from remote [mahout-0.8 dependency](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.8/pom.xml). How to exclude this dependency (snipped) or it cannot be done remotely?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    ...
</dependency>
```

If it cannot be done in such way, would like to know how to integrate mahout pom to my local project.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the hadoop-core dependency in your second snippet into the `dependencyManagement` section of your pom. This will manage it to whatever version you specify.

Or, if you really really want to stop it from coming from mahout all together, change your mahout dependency to something like the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
    <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
           <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I know this feature. But, in my case I need to delete this hadoop-core dependency from mahout, because some of the classes are old. I don't need it anymore. 1.1.2 is the last version of hadoop-core.

Comment: Managing the version of that dependency will mean that maven will bring in the version you specify (and therefore not the old version). So I don't totally understand why you want to remove it, but I've edited my answer to show how you'd do that anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to do. Many many thanks!